# Is it possible to have zero width window separator?

Tags: vim-windows

I want to remove the split separators without any leftover empty space. Is such functionality exposed?

Comment: Whilst it isn't possible, you can effectively make it "invisible" by setting the foreground and background colour of `VertSplit` to be the same as your background e.g. `:hi VertSplit guifg=bg guibg=bg`.  It still occupies one column though.

Comment: @AndrewHo-Lee Yes, I was aware of that but I need seamless continuity between windows in my imagined specific use case. Only route left is to build a custom UI on top of neovim.

Comment: Fair enough, looks like you're right, it's either patching or building something on top of [neo]vim.

Comment: I knew we'd covered this issue before, but took me a while to find it. Turns out, this question is not _quite_ a duplicate, but it's very strongly related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2938/can-the-split-separator-in-vim-be-less-than-a-full-column-wide?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible. A [NeoVim issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5275) requesting that was closed.